# Is it possible to hide SQL passwords and use them in localhost as well in Heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, mysqli, localhost

I'm planning to make my site for school be able to work with Docker on localhost aswell on Heroku app but I have no idea how to resolve problem with connect.php.

***connect.php:***

```
//For localhost:
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
//Create connection:
$conn = new mysqli($_SERVER['MYSQL_SERVER'],$_SERVER['MYSQL_USER'], $_SERVER['MYSQL_PASS'], $_SERVER['MYSQL_DBNAME']);
// Check connection:
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

For localhost I did require_once with config.php:

```
    $_SERVER['MYSQL_SERVER'] = '(server from localhost/Heroku)';
    $_SERVER['MYSQL_USER'] = '(username from localhost/Heroku)';
    $_SERVER['MYSQL_PASS'] = '(password from localhost/Heroku)';
    $_SERVER['MYSQL_DBNAME'] = '(dbname from localhost/Heroku)';
```

And on localhost with Docker set, it works, and site displays correctly but things get complicated when using site hosted on Heroku because it looks for previously requested for localhost usage - config.php instead of reading data from [Heroku Config Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KyyT.png)

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use environment variables, either set in the docker config or Heroky config

Comment: I'm using Heroku Config Vars already, can you tell me more how to use them in docker config as well?

Comment: just google docker env vars